# PrimeNG components not rendering

Tags: angular, primeng

I am new to Angular and set up a simple application including primeng components.

The page I am building is as simple as this:

```
<p-tabView>
   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1">
   </p-tabPanel>
   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 2">
   </p-tabPanel>
   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 3">
   </p-tabPanel>
</tabView>

<p-panel header="Example Panel">
   Content
</p-panel>
```

I can render the `<p-tabView>` just fine, but when I try to use other components, mainly a simple `<p-panel>` no components are rendered anymore. I can see them in Chrome explorer with a size of 0x0 and containing a `<!--container-->` comment inside.

What I mean is, I get the `<p-tabView>` to render perfectly, as soon as I add a `<p-panel>` to same page, nothing is shown anymore.

My dependencies are:

`Angular ~9.0.5
 primeicons ^2.0.0
 primeng ^9.0.5`

All components are included in my app.module.ts like

```
import {TabViewModule} from 'primeng/tabview';
import {PanelModule} from 'primeng/panel';

...

imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  TabViewModule,
  PanelModule
  ...
]
```

The stylesheets I included are:

```
/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css
/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css
/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css
```

I really have no idea where to start solving this. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you using PrimeFaces?

Comment: Yes, please correct your tagging and title...

Comment: I am not sure how you are including the CSS.  In style.css: @import "primeicons/primeicons.css"; 
 (at sign)import "primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css"; 
(at sign)import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";

Answer (score 0):

You are closing "tabView".
Instead you need to close "p-tabView"